# inputImage = nil : Filtered Image not displaying?

Tags: ios, core-image

Have been developing an image filtering app with the help of online tutorials on bitFountain. The user should be able to select image of photo they have added to an album and then can either add filter to the photo or delete that image.
My delete image functionality runs fine but adding a filter is not working.

I have logged three of the filter instances to the console as they are returned by the method but it comes back as inputImage = nil.

```
2015-10-19 10:41:53.634 FilterApp[78451:28732768] <CISepiaTone: inputImage=nil inputIntensity=1>
2015-10-19 10:41:53.634 FilterApp[78451:28732768] <CIGaussianBlur: inputImage=nil inputRadius=1>
2015-10-19 10:41:53.635 FilterApp[78451:28732768] <CIColorClamp: inputImage=nil inputMinComponents=[0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2] inputMaxComponents=[0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9]>
```

**What exactly does inputImage=nil mean?**

I'm not sure where the code could be going wrong, or if this problem is even external to the code. 
(Using Xcode7 and iPhone 4s simulator.)

Edit: This was the code used to convert to UIImage.

```
- (UIImage *)filteredImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image andFilter:(CIFilter *)filter

{

    CIImage *unfilteredImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage];

    [filter setValue:unfilteredImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    CIImage *filteredImage = [filter outputImage];

    CGRect extent = [filteredImage extent];

    CGImageRef cgImage = [self.context createCGImage:filteredImage fromRect:extent];

    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    return finalImage;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when you use CIImage. But when you display the image it contains nil value. So Convert your CIImage to UIImage.

e.g.

```
 CGImageRef image = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:&actualTime error:&err];

 UIImage *imageDisplay = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
```

It may be helpful to you.

Comment: I actually have this in the code already as per the tutorials. I'll update my question to show the entire piece of code for this (sorry should have added this at the start).